# How do I use switches?

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

This is intended to assist anyone running into issues with understanding and using the `switch` statement, including the use of switches within loops which can frequently be a tripping point for PowerShell users.

The questions I have are as follows:

- How do I use the different arguments and cases supported by a switch?

  - `-Exact`, `-Regex`, `-Wildcard`, `-CaseSensitive`, `-File`
  - `string`, `number`, `variable`, `{expression}`
- Why isn't `break` or `continue` working in my `case` statement in a loop?

  ```
  while ($true) {
      switch ($eval) {
          'some condition' { continue }
          default {
              break
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- I have a `default` `case`, but it's not doing anything?

  ```
  switch ($eval) {
      'default' { 'this should do a thing!' }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, many different use-cases for a `switch` statement, but they ultimately serve to make code more readable than a grand `if-elseif-else` chain.

A `switch` takes a condition (or array of conditions), and tries to match it against cases the author provides.  This condition can be any value.

**An important note about PowerShell switches:** because they can take an array of conditions, they are functionally loops which is why they can be labeled (`:mySwitch switch ()`) and `break`/`continue` keywords work against them.  An argument will be evaluated against each case unless it runs into a `break` or `continue` statement and `default` only applies when no cases are matched.

---

- How do I use the different arguments and cases supported by a switch?

Switches parse through a file line-by-line when using the `-File` parameter.  In this use-case, it's basically running `switch (Get-Content -Path $filePath)` versus passing it a condition:

```
switch -File $filePath {
```

The four arguments impact how `string` cases are matched: `-Exact` (default), `-Regex`, `-Wildcard` (these three are exclusive to each other and the last one on a line is used), and finally `-CaseSensitive`.  Each of these arguments is akin to the comparison operators `-eq`, `-match`, and `-like`.  `-CaseSensitive` makes them function as `-ceq`, `-cmatch`, and `-clike`.  **If an argument is not a string, these do *not* apply to it.**  These arguments are passed before the condition:

```
switch -Regex -CaseSensitive ($eval) {
```

or

```
switch -Wildcard -File C:\Temp\myfile.txt {
```

I feel like a `string` match should be fairly obvious given my above description correlating to comparison operators so I will not cover them further.

I have not had much use for the `$variable` cases and they are not well documented.  When attempting to explore this for the purpose of this answer, I ran into a frozen console when trying to compare to `[pscustomobject]` types so YMMV.

`Number` supports decimals, signed and unsigned integers, e.g.:

```
switch (1.3) {
    1.3 { 'this' }
    default { 'that' }
}
# "this"

switch (-5) {
    -5 { 'that' }
    default { 'this' }
}
# "that"
```

I tested this with `double`, `int`, and `uint64`.

The last case supported is the `expression` and one of my favorite.  When you pass an expression to be evaluated by the switch, it's similar to working with the pipeline.  You access the object with `$_` (or `$PSItem`) and its members are available for access as usual. Example:

```
switch (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem) {
    {$PSItem.Caption -like '*server*'} {
        "You're on a server OS!"
    }
    {$PSItem.Organization} { # truthy evaluation
        "You're part of organization: $($PSItem.Organization)!"
    }
    default {
        "This can't possibly fail!"
    }
}
```

---

- Why isn't `break` or `continue` working in my `case` statement in a loop?

Because a `switch` functions like a loop, those keywords work against the `switch`'s block instead of the encapsulating loop.  To get past this limitation, you need to utilize loop labels:

```
:myLoop while ($true) {
    :mySwitch switch ($eval) {
        'some condition' { continue }
        default {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

In both of these cases, this will `break` or `continue` the `switch`, not the `while` loop.  In order to have control, you need to specify the label you assign, e.g.:

```
:myLoop while ($true) {
    :mySwitch switch ($eval) {
        #if $eval is an array, goes to the next iteration
        'some condition' { continue mySwitch } 
        default {
            break myLoop
        }
    }
}
```

---

- I have a `default` `case`, but it's not doing anything?

This one comes down to being a typo.  `default` is a *keyword* and if you have `'default'`, it's a `string` evaluation.  So in the example, fix this by removing the quotes surrounding the `default` *keyword*.

```
switch ($eval) {
    default { 'this now does a thing!' }
}
```